# How to filter rows after a specific record

Tags: sql, oracle

Since I cannot add a screenshot, here is an example of how my data would look (using oracle sql developer):

USERID = numeric value associated with specific user

ENTRYTYPE = non-numeric values, including "Click, Organic, and Key Action"

SITEACTION = null unless the entrytype = Key Action, then site action will tell you what type of key action, also non-numeric

TOUCHPOINTID = numeric id given to each entry made by each user.  Always distinct

EXAMPLE:  userid 22 has 10 touchpoints.  organic, click, click, click, organic, click, click, key action, organic, click.  <--- these are the values written in entrytype, and then each one has an id associated with it in the touchpointid.  The touchpoint ID is ascending according to timestamp (which i can also pull in if needed).  The siteaction column is null except for when the entry is "key action" where it specifies the key action (example, "video view").

In this example, the last 2 entries occur after the first key action.  I want to filter the data to only show entries up through the first key action.

The goal is to get a count of touchpoint ID before the key action (how many touchpoints does a user need to get to key action?).

Thank you kindly in advance!!

Comment: Data in a heap organized table is inherently unordered.  The concepts of "first", "last", "next", etc. require some way of sorting the data.  How are you sorting the data?  Do you sort by `userid` by `touchpointid` to get the ordered list of touchpoints?

Comment: yes, the data is ordered first by userid and then by touchpointid

Comment: might be i didnot understand the requirement correctly but doesnot this give required output SELECT USERID, TOUCHPOINTID - 1 KEYACTION_CNT  FROM #TEMP WHERE ENTRYTYPE = 'key action'; here is sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49bc7/1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT USERID, ENTRYTYPE ,SITEACTION ,TOUCHPOINTID
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         max(case entrytype when 'key action' THEN 1 END) 
            OVER ( partition by userid order by TOUCHPOINTID
                   rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) As x
  FROM t
)
WHERE x IS NULL;
```